# Error while executing an update statement from SQLCMD (Works in SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a service that generates some statements and then pushes them in to the SQL Server database. However it happens from time to time that some of the statements don't reach its destination and are saved in a text file.

I can successfully execute them in the SSMS when I open them but I would like to automate this process with a job and push them again using the `SQLCMD` and the -i parameter. However I get an error message doing so. Could anyone hint as to why this happens?

Below is the `UPDATE` statement and the error message.

```
UPDATE 
    T_TableName 
SET 
    [dtStart] = CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-13T17:31:37.318', 127), 
    [strName] = N'SampleName', 
    [strNumber] = N'', 
    [nNumericValue] = N'1' 
WHERE 
    guidOfItem = '6feb71c1-c2a2-43a1-8baf-0606719c90d9'
```

Erorr:

> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Server , Line 1
>   UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Comment: You need to issue an explicit `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` at the start of the script.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I will try it.